# Combine 2 google sheets formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I am now working to make a database that will be updated automatically. The problem is, the original format looks like this:

| Name | List | List | List | List |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Name 1 | List 1 | List 2 | List 3 | so on |
| Name 2 | List 1 | List 2 | List 3 | List 4 |

The final result that I want to make is look like this

| Name | List |
| --- | --- |
| Name 1 | List 1 |
| Name 1 | List 2 |

For the first column of the final result, I successfully create this with: `=ARRAYFORMULA(Index(Flatten(Split(Rept(A2:A12&";",8),";"))))`

The second column, I create it with: `=Filter(flatten(B2:I12),Not(ISBLANK(Flatten(B2:I12))))` --> I use filter because there are several names but don't fill up to max number so I want to filter the blank one.

**The problem is** I want to combine both formulas into one if it's possible so I could make it just in one step instead of two. I've explored anything but I am stuck. Please help and any feedback would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try placing the following formula into Row 1 (the header row) of an otherwise empty two-column range:

`=ArrayFormula({"Name","Nominee";QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(FILTER(A2:A,A2:A<>"")&"|"&FILTER(B2:I,A2:A<>"")),"|"),"Select * WHERE Col2 Is Not Null")})`

This creates the headers and all results.

**How It Works:**

The headers "Name" and "Nominee" are assigned as the first row of a virtual array within the curly brackets. These can be changed if you like. The semicolon means "now bump down a row and place the rest underneath."

`FILTER(A2:A,A2:A<>"")&"|"&FILTER(B2:I,A2:A<>"")`

All non-blank names are concatenated to a pipe symbol and all nominations (blank or not) where the name for that row is not blank. This will result in a grid filled with **name|nomination** or **name|** (the latter where a nomination was blank).

`FLATTEN` will form one column from all above results.

`SPLIT` will split that at the pipe symbol, leaving either a name beside a nomination, or a name beside a blank.

`QUERY` will keep only those with nominations in the second column.

---

If your raw data is coming in from a form, that form will be adding rows either to the top or bottom of the data range in the form-data intake sheet. This may cause the above formula to keep adjusting the **A2:A** and **B2:I** ranges down by one every time a new row is added to the top. If that winds up being the case for your situation, use the below version of the formula (being sure, of course, to append the name of the form-data intake sheet to all ranges):

`=ArrayFormula(QUERY(IFERROR(IF(ROW(A:A)=1,{"Name","Nominee"},QUERY(IFERROR(SPLIT(FLATTEN(FILTER(A:A,A:A<>"")&"|"&FILTER(B:I,A:A<>"")),"|")),"Select * WHERE Col2 Is Not Null")),{"",""}),"Select * WHERE Col1 Is Not Null"))`

Comment: This works like wonder! thanks a lot, very much appreciated for the help!

Comment: Happy to help. Would you take a moment now to mark the past as "Best Answer"? This step allows other contributors to see at a glance from the main dashboard which issues have been resolved, while also making it easier for future site visitors to find the most relevant answers. Thanks.